# How pass local variable into another view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have next code:

**posts/_form.html.haml**

```
- cat = Post::CATEGORIES.map { |c| [t(c, scope: :post_categories), c] }
= f.input :category, collection: cat
= f.input :subject, input_html: { class: 'input-block-level' }
= f.input :body, input_html: { rows: 5, class: 'ctrlenter input-block-level expanding' }
= link_to "#", class: 'smiley', role: 'add_smiley', tabidex: 4 do
  %i.icon.icon-smile
  смайлы
= smiles_helper '#post_body'

.form-horizontal
  = f.input :tag_list, input_html: { class: 'input-block-level' }
  - if (current_user.paid? && current_user.moderated_group_ids.include?(@group.id)) || moderator?
    = f.input :comments_disabled, inline_label: true, label: false
.attachments
  = f.simple_fields_for :attachments do |af|
    = render "attachments/#{af.object.asset_type.underscore}", :f => af
.poll{style: "display: none;"}
  %h1 "Новый опрос"
  = f.simple_fields_for :poll do |post|
    = render "polls/poll_fields", f: post
```

**polls/poll_fields.html.haml**

```
= f.error_messages header_message: nil
= f.input :question, disabled: !@poll.editable?(current_user), input_html: { class: 'input-block-level' }
= f.input :results_hidden, as: :boolean, inline_label: 'Скрыть результаты до окончания опроса', label: false
= f.input :from_date, as: :datetime, input_html: { class: 'poll_date' }
= f.input :to_date, as: :datetime, input_html: { class: 'poll_date' }
%h3#poll-items Варианты ответа (не больше пяти)
.item_index  
  = f.simple_fields_for :poll_items do |poll|
    = render template: "polls/poll_item_fields", f: poll
  = link_to_add_association 'Добавить еще вариант', f, :poll_items, 
                               { 'data-association-insertion-method' => 'before',
                                 'data-association-insertion-traversal' => 'next' }
```

**polls/poll_item_fields.html.haml**

```
.poll_row
  .poll_item
    = f.input :answer, input_html: { class: 'ctrlenter expanding' }, label: false, placeholder: 'Введите вариант ответа'
    = link_to_remove_association "удалить", f, { wrapper_class: 'poll_item' }
```

Displayed error:  Showing .../views/polls/poll_item_fields.html.haml where line #3 raised:

undefined local variable or method `f' for #<#:0xbe2d1a2c>

How me correct pass variable f to polls/poll_item_fields.html.haml?

Answer (score 0):

instead of 
`render template: "polls/poll_item_fields", f: poll`

try
 `render "polls/poll_item_fields", f: poll`

Comment: displayed error:  Showing .../views/polls/_poll_fields.html.haml where line #9 raised:

Missing partial polls/poll_item_fields

Comment: sry my fault. what about `render template: "polls/poll_item_fields", locals: { f: poll }`

Comment: Showing ../views/polls/_poll_fields.html.haml where line #10 raised:

Missing partial posts/poll_item_fields

Comment: in none place in your code I see ` posts/poll_item_fields`, where does it come from?

Comment: _form.html.haml from posts/ , but need i call partion view poll_item_fields from views/polls/